# Calendar Extender date picking and converting into correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendarextender

i am picking the value from **calender** extender in **textbox** and i am getting the value in the format `{"MM/dd/yyyy"}` but i want it in the format `{"dd/MM/yyyy"}` in another **textbox**
( `txt_actualrightformat.Text`)  as code shown below

```
DateTime wrongformat = DateTime.Parse(TextBox4.Text);
String rightformat = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", wrongformat.Date);
txt_actualrightformat.Text = rightformat.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` is irespective of the format, format is only for displaying purpose. If you are not getting the right date in `wrongformat` then you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the format. and then  simply

```
txt_actualrightformat.Text = wrongformat.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

**EDIT:**

use `DateTime.ParseExcat` like:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox4.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
txt_actualrightformat = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: still i am getting an error as No overload for method 'ParseExact' takes 1 arguments.                                                       DateTime wrongformat = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox3.Text);   txt_actualrightformat.Text = wrongformat.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: @Ashish, DateTime.ParseExact, takes a format and cultureinfo as parameter, check the edited part of the answer

Answer (score 2):

try these

```
DateTime wrongformat = DateTime.Parse(TextBox4.Text);

txt_actualrightformat.Text =wrongformat.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

or

```
 txt_actualrightformat.Text =String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", _wrongformat )
```

**update:**

i think the date in the **`TextBox4`is really in the wrongformat** :-)
Note that **"22/3/2013"**  It matches the format **"d/M/yyyy"** and **doesn't match the format "dd/MM/yyyy"**. - for **"dd/MM/yyyy"** it should be **"22/03/2013"**.

```
DateTime dt;

if(DateTime.TryParseExact(TextBox4.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out td))
{
  // Valid date used in `TextBox4` (NOTE : dd/MM/yyyy)!, you can use dt now as i explained above!.:-)
}
```

Comment: this code is not working,still i am getting the date in {"MM/dd/yyyy"}

Comment: what are you entering in TextBox4 and what are you getting in wrongformat

Answer (score 0):

Before parsing or converting any datetime value check your calendar's date format. on your aspx page go to the calendarExtender and go to its properties then find format and set the format to dd/MM/yyyy and todays date format also do the same. Then from your code behind declare a variable in datetime type and simply pass the text box  value which calendarExtender puts the date on and convert the textbox value in date time. The code will be like
public DateTime date{get;set;}

date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text.ToString()); 
In sql server the value will save like "2016-02-09 00:00:00.000" this format

Comment: are you sure that there is a sql server ;-)